# bitmap display programming in C

Tags: display, c, image

I have been working in DOS in the stoneage with C graphics. I want to display a bitmap that is computed as an array in the format my_bytes(x,y). In dos an fixed pointer address to the hardware bitmap area could be declared but what is best practice under linux.
I am planning to port some of my old dos image processing C-programs (turbo C) to linux. 
A reference to a comprehensive source of info would be great..

/Mikael

Answer (score 4):

### Framebuffer

Very similar thing is possible in Linux using so called `framebuffer`. It's a lowlevel graphics interface on Linux. You can interact with it using `/dev/fb0` device. After opening this device you can call bunch of `ioctl` calls on it in order to configure it (setup resolution, `BPP`, etc) and query it's current settings. Then, you can just write bytes to the file in order to paint some graphics. You can use `mmap` system call in order to map this file in memory. This way you will be able to just write bytes to some memory region and they will apear on the screen. You can find quite good tutorial on this [here](http://raspberrycompote.blogspot.fr/).

Since `framebuffer` is low level interface, your application wont even need any graphical server (like X server/wayland etc) running. You will be able to run your application straight from Linux command line. It should also make your porting very easy as this should be quite similar to what you had in DOS.

This unfortunately also means that your application wont play nice with other windowed applications on the system.

### Other possibilities

If, on the other hand, you don't want to be so lowlevel, you can use one of existing graphical libraries out there. [libsdl](http://libsdl.org/) could be your first candidate. It's very portable (it runs on Linux, Windows, Windows CE, Mac OS X, most BSD and even on Risc OS or Atari and that's not the whole list), there is a lot of documentation out there and a lot of games, emulators and similar software uses it. In addition to graphics, it also gives you unified input (keyboard, mouse, joystick) and audio API (and you probably need all that for your game).

Comment: Will look into sdl, it seems to provide all I need and more... Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @MikaelGustafsson: Since you are new here, I would like to point you out that it is a very good practice on SE to upvote/downwote/accept answers to your questions. I hope you will consider doing this with mine answer.